# FreeMarker Editor in eclipse 3.5 giving Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, freemarker

I am trying to use the freemarker editor in eclipse 3.5 Galileo and found the exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3865)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3799)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3770)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.setStyleRanges(StyledText.java:9029)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.setStyleRanges(StyledText.java:9123)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.applyTextPresentation(TextViewer.java:4801)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.changeTextPresentation(TextViewer.java:4853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.presentation.PresentationReconciler.applyTextRegionCollection(PresentationReconciler.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.presentation.PresentationReconciler.processDamage(PresentationReconciler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.presentation.PresentationReconciler.access$3(PresentationReconciler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.presentation.PresentationReconciler$InternalListener.inputDocumentChanged(PresentationReconciler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.fireInputDocumentChanged(TextViewer.java:2870)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.setDocument(TextViewer.java:2919)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.setDocument(SourceViewer.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.setDocument(SourceViewer.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.initializeSourceViewer(AbstractTextEditor.java:3951)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractTextEditor.java:3466)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.createPartControl(StatusTextEditor.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2857)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2762)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2685)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2676)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler.execute(OpenResourceHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler.run(OpenResourceHandler.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.ActionDelegateHandlerProxy.execute(ActionDelegateHandlerProxy.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.executeCommand(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.press(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:824)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.processKeyEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.filterKeySequenceBindings(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.access$3(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1027)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1040)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:3946)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4589)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3471)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
```

I replaced the freemarker jar in plugin directory and I am using clean option also .. but couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 0):

[FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a bit old (latest release in [December 2008](http://freemarker.blogspot.com/)).

Can you check you reproduce the problem with eclipse Ganymede 3.4(.x), that is older version, or eclipse 3.5.1 (more recent)?
SWT might have evolve in non-compatible way since then. Or it might just be an old bug still un-resolved (like the [115253 one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=115253), or [the 287886](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=287886), which should have been fixed [in 282218](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282218), but for Mac and probably only in 3.5.1).

Answer (score 0):

There's no mention of Freemarker classes in the above stack trace. What editor are you using?

I have Eclipse 3.5.20090621-0832 and Freemarker IDE 1.1.0.M1-N200906060434-H241 and both are working fine. Freemarker IDE is part of [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools/).

You can get the [latest development milestone](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/jboss/FreeMarkerIDE-1.1.0.v200910281724M-H247-M4.zip) (stable releases only support Eclipse 3.4.2) - note that it requires Eclipse 3.5.1 / Galileo SR1.

Or, if you're using Eclipse's built-in package management, update site is [here](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/) along with [installation instructions](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/update)

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same problem and tracked it down to:

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php ?>
```

Basically, it seems like, this Exception is thrown b/c the parser is confused by certain combinations of HTML and PHP.

I can have this Exception thrown just by creating a new PHP-file and fill it with something like that. But the odd thing is it seems like after playing around with it a while makes the Exception disappear. So maybe it's a Unicode-thing neutralized by my editing after a while.

Anyway, there you go.

Best

Raffael